# Return Entire Array for lowest value of one value inside of secondary array

Tags: php, arrays, min

I am sure this question has been asked but i cant find it so here goes...

I have this code   (have to use php 5.3)

```
foreach ($array["Book"] as $abeBooks) {

$abeResult[$i] = array(
            'itemCondition' => $abeBooks['itemCondition'],
            'isbn13' =>$abeBooks['isbn13'],
            'listingPrice' =>$abeBooks['listingPrice'],
            'Link' =>$abeBooks['listingUrl'],
            'sellerRating'=>$abeBooks['sellerRating'],

);

 $isbn13[$i] = $abeBooks["isbn13"];
 $itemCondition[$i] = $abeBooks["itemCondition"];
 $sellerRating[$i] =$abeBooks['sellerRating'];
 $Price[$i] = $abeBooks["listingPrice"];
 $Link[$i] =$abeBooks['listingUrl'];

$i++; }
```

**it returns :**

```
[{"itemCondition":"Fair","isbn13":"9780134167398","listingPrice":"123.5","Link":"www.abebooks.com\/servlet\/BookDetailsPL?bi=22403600014&cm_ven=sws&cm_cat=sws&cm_pla=sws&cm_ite=22403600014","sellerRating":"4"},{"itemCondition":"Very Good","isbn13":"9780134167398","listingPrice":"140.22","Link":"www.abebooks.com\/servlet\/BookDetailsPL?bi=22334428082&cm_ven=sws&cm_cat=sws&cm_pla=sws&cm_ite=22334428082","sellerRating":"4"},{"itemCondition":null,"isbn13":"9780134167398","listingPrice":"480.7","Link":"www.abebooks.com\/servlet\/BookDetailsPL?bi=22173609508&cm_ven=sws&cm_cat=sws&cm_pla=sws&cm_ite=22173609508","sellerRating":"4"}]
```

**what i would like to do is find if the lowest listingPrice if the itemCondition is good,very good, fine, or new and return the entire array for that item ex for this it would return**

```
({"itemCondition":"Fair","isbn13":"9780134167398","listingPrice":"123.5","Link":"www.abebooks.com\/servlet\/BookDetailsPL?bi=22403600014&cm_ven=sws&cm_cat=sws&cm_pla=sws&cm_ite=22403600014","sellerRating":"4"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establish the conditions you'll accept

```
$conditions = array('Fair', 'Very Good', 'Fair', 'New');
```

Filter the array to only include items with those conditions

```
$results = array_filter($abeResult, function($book) use ($conditions) {
    return in_array($book['itemCondition'], $conditions);
});
```

Sort the resulting array in ascending order by listingPrice

```
usort($results, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['listingPrice'] < $b['listingPrice']) return -1;
    if ($a['listingPrice'] > $b['listingPrice']) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

The lowest price will be your first result.

```
$result = reset($results);
```

Comment: this gives me an output of false for result and if i try to output results i get blank brackets

Comment: @ForgivenIT Oh yeah, probably because I accidentally used object notation instead of arrays. I updated the answer.

Comment: I was scratching my head on how that worked with object notation, thought i missed something thanks for the update, save me a massive headache

Comment: Sorry about that, I was lazy and just decoded your JSON output to  generate the data to test this code with. I initially forgot you were working with an array to begin with.

Comment: if i need to ask another question let me know--so now i need to do the same thing but search a different part of the array--exc     $international = array("%international%",  "%Internatational%","%Global%");   would search the array before the above search  but it would search ['vendorDescription'] instead, then it would search for conditions as above that worked.. is this possible or should i do it a totally differnt way